# JavaScript performance: is it better to use an object variable, or an AJAX request, for large amounts of unchanging data?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, javascript-objects

So I have a large amount of data, formatted as a JavaScript object, that my website needs access to. Because this data will not be updated, I have two options: create a JavaScript file and paste in the data as a variable. Or, I can upload the data as a JSON file, and then use an Ajax request to get the data and parse it into an object.

Here's some code to demonstrate what I mean.

**Option 1** (save data as a JS object variable in a separate JS file):

File **`object.js`**

```
let myData = {
    "1": "A",
    "2": "B",
    "3": "C",
    "4": "D",
    "5": "etc..."
};
```

...And so on, except my data is very large, so this file ends up being 25,000+ lines.

And I use the variable like this in some **`script.js`**

```
let myVar5 = myData["5"];
```

---

**Option 2** (save data as JSON, do Ajax magic, and parse into JS object)

file **`object.json`**

```
{
    "1": "A",
    "2": "B",
    "3": "C",
    "4": "D",
    "5": "etc..."
}
```

And then in my **`script.js`** I do this:

```
let url = "/data/object.json";
$.getJSON(url, function(response) {
    let data = JSON.parse(response);
    let myVar5 = data["5"]
}
```

Which option would have better performance, in terms of memory, speed, storage, and other practical stuff for websites on the internet?

Comment: ajax would be slower; scripts are well optimized.

Comment: I wouldn't think there is much different between the js file and the ajax retrieval.  Both are going to incur a network request to retrieve the data, and both are going to store the information some where in the users environment.

Comment: How large? If under 1m don't see why the overhead of using json parsing and stuff.. and some loaded files.

Comment: It's better to put it in a script as a Javascript object as you won't have to JSON.parse it then.

Comment: This question is awfully broad: "better performance, it terms of every performance measurement available". Please narrow the question to what you think are the pertinent issues. Note that the best way to test any performance is by testing the performance in your application under the conditions most likely to be used by your users.

Comment: Also, if this data should be available to other apps via APIs and stuff then it might make more sense to actually store it in JSON standard.. You should provide more information on use cases, how large is the data and everything else which might be relevant

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments and advice. I know my question was pretty vague, but very new to optimization and performance so I'm not exactly sure what I should be looking for. As for your questions: the data doesn't need to be accessible to others, only needed on this webpage (at least for now). I understand that if it's gonna be released as an API, JSON is the way to go. And for how large, it's an object with 20 sub-objects, each with anywhere from 100 to 250 sub-objects, each with 12 properties. So that's 48,000 properties by my back-of-the-napkin calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Which option would have better performance, in terms of memory, ...

The JSON variant is 7 bytes shorter

> ... speed, ...

If you don't need the JSON to render the page for the first time, loading it afterwards from a JSON file will be better as it gets loaded after the page rendered, also parsing JSON is probably faster as JS is much more complicated to parse (but were probably talking about nanoseconds).

> ... storage, ...

not sure how that differs from memory. Maybe both files get cached, maybe not, that depends on the browser etc.

> ... and other practical stuff for websites on the internet?

I wouldn't go with the hardcoded variant as my IDE would try to parse the file to hint me about its types and properties, which will slow down my development process. It doesnt parse files loaded externally.

Comment: Appreciate the quick reply. I had a feeling the answer would end up being...it's not gonna make a huge difference either way. But I'm very new to performance issues on the web, so I appreciate your help. Thanks so much!

Comment: @noah There is not much you need to know about performance in general, [there is just one golden rule](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)